# How to get a file where a class defined or how to track that class was changed (Scala)?

Tags: scala, file, class, playframework

We are trying to implement a module in our app that requires knowledge of whether or not a specific class was updated. Think about a class that defines a migration logic and we need to know if one of these migrations been updated and reapply them when needed.

There are couple of potential options:

1. Track if a file, where migrations defined, was changed.
2. Track if the class itself was changed (if possible).

For #1, my question is how to the the file where a class was defined. We need that, because  we already have classes loaded.
For #2 - is it even possible. If yes, how?

Or, there might be completely different approach. Any through helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Or keep a version number in the class itself. Why do you need to do it by looking at the class or file? It seems rather fragile and also will flag changes to the class that don't actually affect users (renaming a private member, for instance).

Comment: You can look at the code of sbt or play to see how they do that?

What kind of migrations are you trying to develop? DB?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The problem with that approach is that developer needs to remember to update that version number every time he changes the code.

Comment: @MichałSznurawa we building migration for our internal data structures. And the idea is similar to Play evolutions: if evolution gets changed, Play will migrate down and then back up again with a new version. But, in out case it's a bit more complex than just SQL statement., we actually have to do it through migration class.

Comment: Well, no. You can make updating the number automatic as part of your build (I've done this sort of thing in the past).

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul What about development cycle. This is where it is actually much more important. there is no build running at that point, just 'sbr ~run' watches the code changes.

Comment: Can't you set up sbt to make that change? Also, basically, this is the same issue as SerialVersionUID attempts to solve. Can you use that, perhaps?

Comment: But, SerialVersionUID  is usually statically set.

Comment: Yes, but that's because in many cases changes to the class don't change the serialization. But it can be automatically set, and that seems to be (more or less) what you're looking for here.  But, really, I'd worry if you have developers changing this key class without the organizational ability to know to increment a version number....